# Is there a way to disagree with the review systems "recommendation"

Tags: feature-request, review, low-quality-posts, disputed-review-audits

When approving a post that system thinks should not have you are presented with something along the lines of

> This post has severe quality issues. It is abusive nonsense, noise,
> spam, blatantly off-topic or otherwise irredeemable - readers will
> find it offensive or repulsive rather than helpful. You should delete
> or recommend deletion when reviewing such posts.
>
> Don't worry, we've already handled this post appropriately - but
> please take a minute to look it over closely, keeping in mind the
> guidance shown above.

With a "I understand" button, what about if you disagree with that assertion? Is there a way to indicate that? If there isn't perhaps one should be added so that data can be collected to improve the system.

For example:

While reviewing the low quality posts queue I got the following answer from [yegor256](https://stackexchange.com/users/63162/yegor256)
to to the question https://stackoverflow.com/q/11362889/384985

> Try [s3auth.com](http://www.s3auth.com/) (I'm a developer). It does exactly what you're
> looking for, free of charge.

Which I approved and the system responded that I should have recommended deletion.

From what it looks like to me the OP is asking a question about adding basic username/password authentication for an Amazon s3 hosted website and the answer is mentioning a free product/service that does what the user wants. It is true that the user answering is affiliated (they posted a disclaimer) with the product but from what I understand that is [allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#promotion).

Comment: I agree. If the system can ***handled this post appropriately***, then why have reviewers at all? And as the OP said, a "Disagree" button would provide valuable feedback to make the system better.

Comment: Your example is a textbook example of a low quality post...

Comment: @sixlettervariables Can you elaborate why you think so? Since from what I see it's a short answer but it seems to provide exactly what the OP was looking for.

Comment: It should be a comment if anything, beyond the fact the question is a shopping question / gimme teh codez.

Comment: @Jack Link only answers are discouraged. What if the link breaks? Then the answer basically becomes useless. Including a brief snippet about how to use the library, for example, would have made it acceptable.

Answer (score 3):

Those posts are not actually flagged as low quality by the system, or voted to close. Instead, they are selected by a (seemingly) separate algorithm, and supposed to be "gotchas" introduced in the review queues to test our ability to detect low-quality or closable posts.

If you disagree with the system, post on Meta like you did. [I recently did the same myself](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/146438/167534).

Comment: Still, a "Disagree" button to tell the developers "I think your gotchas selection algorithm needs improvement" with less effort would be useful, I believe.

Comment: It would, but... Do you encounter such cases so often to justify a feature like that?

Comment: @bfavaretto yes, I did. I don't review anymore though, and won't until there's a built in dispute mechanism.