# Reviewing close votes: what to do when I disagree with a "you didn't pay attention"?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, review, vote-to-close

While reviewing close votes on SO, I was presented with this question:

[How to implement recursive blocks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18791664/how-to-implement-recursive-blocks)

which - in my opinion - is much too broad (the OP added no less than three additional sub-questions).

The voting system told me that I hadn't paid attention and this question should be left open. I disagree, and I'd like to support the proposal of a "disagree with this" button or similar (as was already suggested in [Meta question on how to disagree with the review systems recommendation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/146790/is-there-a-way-to-disagree-with-the-review-systems-recommendation)

I don't mind the system telling me when I made a mistake - as long as I can tell the system when *it* is making a mistake, as well :-)

Comment: If you agree with another proposal then just upvote it, don't post a duplicate question just to say you like it.

Comment: I already upvoted it, but since the situation described in the post was the other way round (the reviewer approved the post where the system did not, whereas I as reviewer disapproved the post and the system did approve), I thought it merited a different question. Feel free to vote for close if you disagree.

Comment: I agree, there needs to be some built in way to dispute audits [even if the system still marks my audit as failed](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/191262/142853). The forced "agreement" is very annoying for me, and the difficulty in correcting a bad audit post is just bad for SE in general.